# develop sharepoint webservice and deploy it to sharepoint site

Tags: web-services

Recently I am developing a webservice which is used to upload document to a SharePoint doc library. I have deploy it to the _vti_bin directory and now I can successfully call it to upload a document. However, no matter what I use as username and password, the owner of upload document is still System Account. It shows in the site as modified by System Account. I refer to "[Walkthrough: Creating a Custom ASP.NET Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/ms464040.aspx) ([Eng version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx))" to develop and deploy webservice.
The code for calling the webservice is the following:

```
string FileUrl = "d:/bbb.txt";
sharepoint_0907.Service ss = new sharepoint_0907.Service();
ss.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
byte[] fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@FileUrl);
int s = ss.UploadFile("http://sharepoint01/Shared Documents/", 
                       fileContents, "http://sharepoint01", "123.txt");
string ddd = ss.HelloWorld();
```

So I can successfully upload a document with view user who has not have authority to upload a document. And this is not what I want. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have elevated code you get System Account as modifier of the documents. Also if you have Claims based authentication it makes things more complicated.

I was struggling with similar issues to get correct authentication in web-service calls. The msdn article you are using is not too easy to follow - I was using this [blog post by Arjun Chakraborty](http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a%2Dd0ef%2D4258%2Dbe2a%2D28487dc9975c&ID=64), except the part where you push web.config with deploy to the hive and overwrite the existing ISAPI web.config - just edit the web.config manually. Also I used a binding **TextStreamBindingNoSecurity** that SharePoint built-in web-services uses. This also works for https using **TextStreamBindingHttpsNoSecurity** binding.

Answer (score 0):

Would using the OOB Copy Web Service help you get rid of custom Web Service and also fix this issue?
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787610/how-do-you-copy-a-file-into-sharepoint-using-a-webservice)